# SmartGWT DateTimeItem: accept 12 hour format

Tags: smartgwt

I am using the SmartGWT DateTimeItem component. By default, the component accepts time in the 24 hour format (ie 11:15, 15:30). I would like to know how I can configure the component to accept the time in 12 hour format (ie 11:15 am, 3:30pm)?

Technical Specs:

- Smart GWT v3.0
- Firefox 11
- IE 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTimeItem.setTimeFormatter(TimeDisplayFormat.TOPADDEDTIME);
```

Haven't tested but it looks like what you want !