# display seconds in DateTimeItem (SmartGWT)

Tags: smartgwt

when reading [SmartGWT DateTimeItem: accept 12 hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177171/smartgwt-datetimeitem-accept-12-hour-format) I found that using `TimeDisplayFormat` offers the options to display the seconds as, e.g. `dateTimeItem.setTimeFormatter(TimeDisplayFormat.TOPADDED24HOURTIME);` well, but there was no change in the displaying of the date.

As the code states that `TimeDisplayFormat` is deprecated, and one should use the `DateDisplayFormatter` instead, I tried `dateTimeItem.setDateFormatter(DateDisplayFormat.TOSERIALIZEABLEDATE);`, but still no change.

The value gets set via `dateTimeItem.setValue(myDate);`

Any idea what (else) I have to set to the `DateTimeItem` in order to get the seconds displayed as well?

I'm using SmartGWT 3.1

PS: I tried `dateTimeItem.setDisplayFormat(DateDisplayFormat.TOSERIALIZEABLEDATE);` as well, but still no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `DateDisplayFormat.TOSERIALIZEABLEDATE` is having some issue in SmartGWT 3.x.

`dateTimeItem.setDateFormatter(DateDisplayFormat.TOSERIALIZEABLEDATE);` works correctly in SmartGWT 4.0.

`dateTimeItem.setDisplayFormat(DateDisplayFormat.TOSERIALIZEABLEDATE);` did not provide required behavior even in 4.0, probably due to a default system wide format setting.

You should be able to use a value formatter as a workaround in 3.0.

```
dateTimeItem.setEditorValueFormatter(new FormItemValueFormatter() {
    public String formatValue(Object value, Record record, DynamicForm form, FormItem item) {
        if (value != null && value instanceof Date) {
            return DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format((Date) value);
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Check [DateItem.setEditorValueFormatter](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/DateItem.html#setEditorValueFormatter%28com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.FormItemValueFormatter%29) as you might have to set input format, etc. as well.

Comment: its working in smartgwt 4, didn't test the workaround for sgwt 3. thanks

Answer (score 0):

hi use  the following code in your dateitem  timeSheetDate.setShowPickerTimeItem(true);   timeSheetDate.setTimeFormatter(TimeDisplayFormat.TOSHORTTIME); and also you can use timeSheetDate.setTimeFormatter(TimeDisplayFormat.TOTIME);